# Wind & wine, child & children

Tags: pronunciation

I'm confused with the logics of pronunciation for some words. Some of them are frequently used in my speaking and I tend to confuse.

The word *wine* sounds different than *wind* in the same part of the word i.e the root *win*; another pair which confused me is *child* / *children*, where on *children* pronunciation of *child* is similar to *chill* at least in my opinion.

Any way to rationalize this or is just memorizing?

Comment: It isn't the logic of pronunciation but of spelling. The sound of vowels and consonants has changed over time. Very long ago spelling was based largely on regional pronunciation. Spelling was then normalized by fiat so that nowadays it is quite universal, with only a few relatively insignificant variations. Since language is always changing there is no way that a newly revised spelling system would not eventually become out of sync again. What's worse is that all existing texts from the past several hundred years would have to be reissued under the "new" spelling, so you'd have to learn both!

Comment: Thanks for the comment although I can't get what you mean. In the example *win* is pronounced differently. Do you mean the words start being used in different times or regions and so they are pronounced differently?

Comment: Pronunciation varies regionally at any given time, and pronunciation also morphs over time.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo yes i understand that. However, it doesn't solve the problem ...they just memorize the pronunciation?

Comment: Yes it does explain the issue. The normalization by fiat imposed a spelling which in many cases did not reflect then-current pronunciation, and which did not have a separate letter for every then-current vowel sound.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo oh I see. So fiat changed the spelling of some words and people retained its old pronunciation?

Comment: Although in a few isolated cases people began to pronounce words as they were spelled, in most cases people just continued to speak as they had always spoken.

Comment: During the Middle English period here's how modern English **sister** was spelled when in the nominative case:  *suster, souster, soster, sister, cister, zoster, swuster*. You can still hear these differences in regional dialects.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Very interesting. You should post an answer I think. And maybe clarify to me what do you refer by fiat, and when it happened...

Comment: An example of "fit": Consider the word spelled today as  **a-g-a-i-n**.  In the second syllable  (-**gain**) the vowel today varies considerably by region and it did so as well at the time of the normalization by fiat.  Some people say|said it with a vowel like in **pain**. Others with a vowel like in **pen**.  Others with a vowel like the one in **pin**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually even more tricky than what you describe.

For example, the word **wind** that you mentioned has multiple senses—and two of those senses are pronounced *differently*. The noun for "a breeze" rhymes with **win** (as you mentioned) but the verb for "to crank" actually *does* rhyme with **wine**.

The only way to know which sense of a word is being used is by context. Once you identify it by context, then you have to just "know" how to pronounce that particular sense.

There certainly are *some* rules. For instance Oxford provides two basic pronunciation guides: one for [the UK](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/about/english/pronunciation_english) and one for [the US](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/about/pronunciation_american_english.html). But there is also a need for memorization and habit where those fail—most often in the case of exceptions.

When I speak, I apply any rules without being aware of them. (Although I do vaguely recall my years in grade school when I was taught some of the basic rules.)

Another problem is regional dialects and accents. In broad terms, one country can pronounce the same words differently than another country. (As shown by the two different Oxford pronunciation guides.) But this is also true of different particular areas within a country—and even different social and cultural groups.

If I were to visit certain places in Wales or Scotland, for instance, or Jamaica or New Orleans (or even English-speaking places in Quebec), I might have difficulty understanding what was being said (as could they have difficulty understanding me). This is despite the fact that we would all be speaking English.